# Under the Assumptions of the Simple Linear Regression Model, Why Is This Term a Chi-Square Random Variable with $n - 2$ Degrees of Freedom?

Tags: regression, normal-distribution, chi-squared-test, degrees-of-freedom

I am told that, under the assumptions of the simple linear regression model, $\dfrac{n\hat\sigma^2}{\sigma^2} \sim \chi^2_{(n - 2)}$. Why is $\dfrac{n\hat\sigma^2}{\sigma^2}$ a chi-square random variable with $n - 2$ degrees of freedom? It seems like it resembles the sum of $n$ squared standard normal variables of the form $\dfrac{\hat\sigma^2}{\sigma^2}$, so my previous knowledge leads me to think that it should have $n$ degrees of freedom? Although, I'm not convinced that it is a squared standard normal variable, since it does not totally resemble the form $\left( \dfrac{X - \bar{X}}{\sigma} \right)^2$.

My question stems from this image:

[image]

From [this page](https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat414/node/280).

Since the other terms take the form of a squared standard normal variable, I understand why they are chi-squared random variables with 1 degree of freedom. However, I do not understand why the last term has $n - 2$ degrees of freedom.

I would greatly appreciate it if people could please take the time to clarify this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One degree of freedom is used to calculate $\bar{x}$, and one degree of freedom is used to calculate $\bar{y}$. These, in turn are used to calculate $\hat{\beta}$ and $\hat{\alpha}$ as well as their sample standard errors. Hence, $n-2$.

Comment: Ahh, I think I understand now. Thank you for the assistance.

Answer (score 1):

Considering the general linear regression model with an error term and $m$ explanatory variables, you can derive the distribution of the variance estimator by presenting it as a scaled quadratic form of the error term.  Letting $h \equiv x (x^\text{T} x)^{-1} x^\text{T}$ denote the [hat matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_matrix), and noting that $h x = x$ gives:

$$\begin{equation} \begin{aligned}
(n-m-1) \hat{\sigma}^2 = \text{SSE} &= || Y - \hat{Y} ||^2 \\[4pt]
&= Y^\text{T} (I - h) Y \\[4pt]
&= \varepsilon^\text{T} (I - h) \varepsilon \\[4pt]
&\sim \sigma^2 \cdot \text{Chi-Sq}(\text{df} = \text{Rank}(h)) \\[4pt]
&= \sigma^2 \cdot  \text{Chi-Sq}(\text{df} = n-m-1). \\[4pt]
\end{aligned} \end{equation}$$

The case for the simple linear regression occurs when $m=1$, when we have:

$$\begin{equation} \begin{aligned}
(n-2) \frac {\hat{\sigma}^2}{\sigma^2} \sim \text{Chi-Sq}(\text{df} = n-2).
\end{aligned} \end{equation}$$

Understanding this deeply requires learning a bit about [quadratic forms for normal random vectors](http://pages.stat.wisc.edu/~st849-1/lectures/Ch02.pdf).  If you just want a rough intuitive explanation then it suffices to note that for each $\beta$ parameter we estimate in the regression, we lose one degree-of-freedom.